# Change DatePickerDialog message color

Tags: android

I have implemented DatePickerDialog in my project, I have set message to DatePickerDialog. But, when I'm running the Project, the message text is coming on white background. I want to change the color of that message text background.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ContactDetailsActivity.this, R.style.UserDialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    Log.d("Orignal", "Got clicked");
                    String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + year;
                    editTextEndDate.setText(date);

                }
            },
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.setMessage("Start date");
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

UserDialog

```
<style name="UserDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:"></item>
</style>
```

I want to make the background of "End date" to colorAccent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2uM.png)

Comment: Show us the`R.style.UserDialog`

Comment: @Dayan check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

In style.xml set color of picker

```
 <color name="colorAccent">"#ffffff"< /color>


TextView date;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
int year;
int month;
int dayOfMonth;
Calendar calendar;
date = findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate);
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                            date.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                        }
                    }, year, month, dayOfMonth);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
```